# Calling abstract method from an object of derived/base class

Tags: c#, inheritance

I am a beginner in C# and trying my hands on inheritance. 
ClassA is base class and classB and classC are derived from classA. My Program class has static method Show(). At first I was not sure whether I will be returning an objectB or objectC. So I did not know what should be return type of method Show(). Setting return type to base class i.e classA solved my problem at first, but when i tried to access MyMethod in Main it throws error because MyMethod is declared abstract in classA. How can I call MyMethod on my returned object?

```
abstract class classA
{
    protected abstract void MyMethod();
    // other fields and methods
}

class classB: classA
{
    protected override MyMethod()
    {
        //logic
    }
}

class classC: classA
{
protected override MyMethod()
    {
    //logic
    }
 }


class Program
{
    public static classA Show()
        {
            if(condition)
                { //logic
                return objectB;  //objectB is instantiated from classB
                }
            else
                {//logic
                return objectC;  //objectC is instantiated from classC
                }
        }

    static void Main(string[] args)
        {
         ClassA myObject = Show();
         myObject.MyMethod();
        }
}
```

Comment: Change MyMethod to public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make the MyMethod public.

```
abstract class classA
{
    public abstract void MyMethod();
    // other fields and methods
}

internal class classB : classA
{
    public override void MyMethod()
    {
        //logic
    }
}

internal class classC : classA
{
    public override void MyMethod()
    {
        //logic
    }
}
```